# how to get special characters from windows to mac

Tags: windows-10, macos, virtualbox

for some development we need to boot into a windows vm(Virtualbox) on a mac but in this system the special characters don't work like eg:

{} [] \

is there a way to pass these characters ? from mac to windows. this is mainly for .net win forms since this is not support on mac.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "special characters don't work".

Comment: if i want to type a backslash i can not get the character only / is working

Comment: So it's a keyboard layout issue? UK keyboards as example, backslash on a Mac is 3rd key to the right of L, on a PC it's left of Z. You need to check your input languages/keymaps for both.